# Integrating Slices in Android Google Search

Tags: android, kotlin, google-search, android-slices

I have implemented slices from [Google android developers tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/getting-started). My code is working exactly fine in SliceViewer App.But I don't know how to show this with google search app result.Can someone tell me how to integrate this operation and how will the google search know when to display my slice data?

Comment: The slices is still not live for users, you can only test them with Slice Viewer

Comment: Does anyone know when slices are going to be available to the wide audience?

Comment: Hello, how about android slices in 2020? I am asked to do some demos to show our app slices in google search. But, I am finding no slice in Google Search yet even though the docs says _Slices are UI templates that can display rich, dynamic, and interactive content from your app from within the **Google Search app** and also in other places like the Google Assistant._